# How do you secure a Windows 11 PC connected directly to modem without a router?

Tags: network, router, windows-11, modem

I saw [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64073/connecting-a-secure-computer-directly-to-the-internet-without-a-router) but it focused more on Linux. It sounds to me that the main thing that makes using a router more secure is the fact that it blocks any inbound stuff, which sounds simple enough to set up on the PC itself, but I don't know how to do that on Windows 11.

Especially considering that I've seen lots of articles about various routers having unfixable security issues, it seems with a little tweaking and possibly some 3rd party software it would be possible to make a Windows 11 system just as, if not more secure than using a router. Or am I entirely wrong and this is a bad idea? Or just overly complicated and carries too big a risk of mistakes?

Is it possible to do this using only Windows's built-in firewall and virus protection? If not will whatever software needed be using significantly more resources to run than them?

Comment: You can also do the same on Windows Firewall and you should disable UPnP on your PC then.

Comment: in addition to SirM's suggestion, i would also review all of the listening services running on the windows host and disable any that aren't in use - one way to do this is to use the [SysInternals suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/), in particular, the tools `tcpview.exe` and `autoruns.exe` .. (ps. watch out if you type this into a search engine for a link, as there is at least one domain that looks deceptively similar to the spelling of "sysinternaLs")